# Найти в тексте ссылку PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, ссылки, виджет

Сама задача стоит непосредственно для виджета Wordpress. В каждом артикле блога присутствуют ссылки типа "https://www.test.com/primer/primer2/stranica", а задача стоит следующая: найти первую ссылку ведущую на "https://www.test.com/primer/primer2/" и создать переменную, которая бы взяла значение "stranica". Реально ли это сделать? Если да, то как? Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: На счёт штатного инструментария Wordpress я не уверен, а вот с помощью регулярных выражений это вполне можно решить: [см.пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/99574837fd2f4af313935c8903a655d8750c7c30)

Comment: @Эдуард да, регулярное выражение поможет найти ссылку, но меня больше всего затрудняет вопрос, как найти именно последнее слово в этой ссылке и присвоить его как значение переменной

Comment: так я же вам и написал пример, в котором в переменную `$url` сохраняется ссылка, а в переменную `$page` - последнее слово. Ну имена переменных самостоятельно подкорректируете при необходимости.

Comment: @Эдуард все, вижу, спасибо огромное, сейчас буду пробовать!

Comment: Непонятно... что такое "артикль блога", что такое "ссылка php" и зачем её надо искать в каком-то "тексте", если все ссылки сайта и так известны? А в ВП есть родные функции для получения пред/след записей.

Comment: @SeVlad речь идет о самом тексте в посте. Скажем так, на сайте 100 постов, в каждом из них, в тексте, есть ссылка на другой сайт. То есть, например, у нас новостной блог, в каждом из постов есть, допустим рекламная ссылка на сайт продажи какой-нибудь техники. Вот у нас статья о HP, и блогер засунул ссылку, мол, а купить в HP можно тут www.magazin.ru/komputer/hp 
А мне необходимо приучить виджет искать марку продукции через ссылку.

Comment: @SeVlad сейчас как раз пытаюсь сделать поиск через $post_content, но конечно же ничего не получается )

Comment: какой ужас... Но я по-прежнему  не понимаю ни про "артикль блога" ни про "следующие" ссылки , а теперь к этому добавилось еще и "приучить виджет". Зачем? Какая конечная цель?  Но чую, что задачу нужно решать по другому.

Comment: @SeVlad Я объясню для чего это нужно. У нас 100500 постов и все они, если говорить о технике, о разных компаниях. Какая-то про Apple, другая статья о Samsung, третья о Phillips. А мой виджет должен "понять" о какой компании идет речь в статье (чтобы добавить баннер с совершенно иной ссылкой, на третий сайт). Потому что названия статей абсолютно рандомны, например "Акции Apple поднялись на 1,5%". И лучшее пока, что мне удалось придумать это ловить уже имеющиеся ссылки в этих статьях, которые присутствуют всегда. И уже отталкиваясь от последнего слова в этой ссылке, делать свою собственную.

Comment: Чтобы "понять" - существует масса "сигналов" - рубрики, метки, произвольные поля и ещё 100500 способов можно придумать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно взять ссылку и разделить на слеши. 
  Этот код выведет массив:

```
$link = "http://www.test.com/page1/page2/page3";
$alink = explode("/",$link);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($alink);
echo "</pre>";
```

И таким образом выводим page3:

```
echo $alink[5]; // Выведет page3
```

Также спокойно можешь записать отдельно в переменную.

Comment: Для этих целей лучше использовать `parse_url`

Comment: И почему же parse_url лучше?

Comment: Потому что он создан специально для разбора url

Comment: Ну и    explode  справляется с этим хорошо